# Ubuntu 22.04 :: VM failure after power failure

Tags: virtualization

I have Several VM's - **all worked fine prior that event**.
After a grid power failure - all VM's showing an error message as shown below.
PC works fine. All files, HDD, are intact.
I tried to `Ignore` - but problem persists.

What can I do ?

[image: screenShot]

Comment: The error tells you to visit their support site.

Comment: @David ,  since it an error with no specific error tag or similar, I have nothing to search.

Comment: Depending on the file system inside the VM, you may have a lot of missing `inode` data, which could prevent the system from having a consistent volume to boot from. You’ll probably need to boot each Linux VM with an Ubuntu Desktop ISO (temporarily, of course) in order to use the tools in the installation media to test the volumes and search for boot errors.

Comment: @matigo It doesn't add up, since only one of them was running at that time (ha3). All of the VM's generate this exact message upon start.
Can you explain the second part, how to do this?

Comment: If this is happening to “all”, then the issue is likely in the VM manager itself. Reinstallation of VirtualBox may be necessary. I have not been keeping up with the internal changes inside VBox for the past year or so, but it’s very much an Oracle product, meaning that power failures (and full disks) can result in some impossible-to-trace problems. Oracle software does not like to lose control of any situation … much like Larry Ellison 